# Converting table with bigger than or equal and empty values to MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a form for MCQ scale called "Spence" which consists of 6 groups of questions. Each answer is a number like this:

1- Question 1

Never(0 points) Sometimes(1 point) Often(2 points) Always(3 points)

At the end of the test, each group's total score is calculated from the answers. Then with this score, I open a table provided by the test to get some other values like `T-Score`.

I want to convert the tables they provided to MYSQL (one or multiple MYSQL tables). This is one of the tables:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JJZV.png)

What happens is that I have a value with one of the 6 columns on the left to get the values of the 3 columns to the right.

The issue is that some values on the left columns look like this `>=8` and this `4-5`.

I was thinking of creating a table with this structure:

```
id | min_ocd | max_ocd | min_social_phobia | max_social_phobia | ..  | total_scas | t_score | percentile
1  | 0       | 0       | 13                | 13                | ..  | 14         | 48      | 43%
.. | ..      | ..      | ..                | ..                | ..  | ..
10 | 8       | 1000    | 13                | 13                | ..  | >=53       | >=70    | >=98%
```

Query example where 1 is the total score from answers:

```
SELECT 
    t_score
FROM table
WHERE total_ocd_raw_score BETWEEN min_ocd and max_ocd
```

There are 4 tables like the one in the screenshot.

Is there a better way with some SQL functions or a different structure?

Comment: Your `total_scas` and scoring/percentile won't be stored .. They will be a result of your query and calculated in real time .. That way if John's OCD is treated and his score goes down, it will reflect in the `totals` result panes without having to edit those every time there is a change.

Comment: Something like `SELECT SUM(min_ocd, max_ocd, ..., ...) as total_scas WHERE conditionals`

Comment: @Zak I tried to figure out how these 3 columns are calculated even from the scale t-scores they provided I couldn't get the same values. If I can calculate them no need to save any data at all.

Comment: Agreed with Zak. To expand on it a little bit, even though it's in the same "table" in your input data. At a row level, columns 1-6 look like they are entirely unrelated to 7-9. Could be wrong, not sure how to interpret this. But assuming that, you'd store 7-9 separately as a lookup, and join to it based on the (sum?) of 1-6 when loading your final result.

Comment: A quick Google search [Revealed the T-Score calculation method](https://www.scaswebsite.com/portfolio/scas-child-t-scores/)

Comment: @Zak I came across it while searching too but as I mentioned there are 3 more tables and it seems t-scores are calculated depending on the percentile and I don't know how it's calculated from the raw score.

Comment: Now that I have a better understanding ..  I would just create a Excel doc ..  4 tabs that all indicate "Boys 8-11" etc --  In each sheet I would create rows 7 - 53 tscore and fill in the corresponding score (anxieties / phobias) -- this is a hard chart that does not change.  I would then under the chart put checkboxes and inputs for the form.  Write the formula(s), so as you fill it out, it will calculate via the chart in real time.  No need for complicated storage and queries in this case.  Once the chart is created, you can "hide" it too so you only see the form.

Comment: A [mre] example, input data with desired output, will be needed to help you. This need not be an input sheet of 10 row by 6 columns, because the problem can also be described in less columns....  But, i think, you need the source data because when having `OCD='>=8'`  You **need** to know if that value is `9` or `99` (or any other value) to do something with that value in te right columns.

Comment: @Zak It's required to be a MYSQL database because it will be used for an online web form.

Comment: Please share complete readable input data (See: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) ), and desired output.  Question is way to complex to just guess what you do want to have without proper data.

Comment: What dependency is there between "Never(0) Sometimes(1) Often(2) Always(3)" and the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JJZV.png) you provided ? (This dependency is unclear to me)

Comment: @Luuk these are the answers for each question each answer has a score from 0-3 the total score is then used with the 6 columns to the left. The questions are divided into 6 groups each group represents one of the 6 columns i.e questions 1-12 represent the 1st column.

Comment: So far (up until you have the answers to the questions asked), i created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/_bifuRxS.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for your effort I appreciate it but  I don't want the calculation of score. I want to save the table in MYSQL https://www.scaswebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/SCAS-P-Boys-7-9-FinalJune2018copyV2.pdf

Comment: Yes, but (as I understand) the source of this PDF is coming from questions answered. So I started creating 3 tables (`persons`, `questions` and `answers`) to start with a [mre] of your problem.  The next step would be to use this and get the `T-score` (when I am right), but I do not have a clue how to do that.

Comment: @Luuk I don't need the rest of the system. I just need this table created in MYSQL. I will do the rest.

Comment: My problem is "**this table**", it's still not clear which table you are talking about .... (A PDF is not a table)   I am trying to find the **gap** between this PDF, and [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) 

Comment: @Luuk The PDF contains the table. I need the one with 9 columns 6 to the left and 3 to the right. The question has a screenshot of the table. It could be multiple MySQL tables but I need to create the table in PDF in MYSQL

Comment: Sorry, I stop (trying to) help you with that ...